# replacing the n-th element from a variadic template list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I tried to use [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412010/2081073) to get the following working:
(replacing the n-th element from a variadic list and packing it as a tuple)

```
template<typename... Ts>
using pack_as_tuple = std::tuple<Ts...>;


template< std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct replace_nth_type_in_list
{
    typedef replace_nth_type<N,T, pack_as_tuple<Ts...>> type;
};


int main()
{
    using U = std::tuple<std::string,unsigned,size_t,double>;
    using rep0 = replace_nth_type<0,char,U>::type;
    using rep1 = replace_nth_type<1,char,U>::type;
    using rep2 = replace_nth_type<2,char,U>::type;
    using rep3 = replace_nth_type<3,char,U>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<rep0, std::tuple<char,unsigned,size_t,double>>::value, "Error!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<rep1, std::tuple<std::string, char,size_t,double>>::value, "Error!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<rep2, std::tuple<std::string, unsigned,char,double>>::value, "Error!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<rep3, std::tuple<std::string, unsigned,size_t,char>>::value, "Error!");

    using repList0 = replace_nth_type_in_list<0,char,std::string,unsigned,size_t,double>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<repList0, std::tuple<char,unsigned,size_t,double>>::value, "Error!");
    return 0;
}
```

But the last static assert is triggered. You can see the live example [HERE](http://liveworkspace.org/code/gHacs$0)
Can somebody explain to me, why this happens and how to solve this?

Comment: The link to the live example is broken for me. How are you defining `replace_nth_type`?

Comment: The functions are defined in the answer I linked - is this one better: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Qqz2V$0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! It's this line:

```
typedef replace_nth_type<N,T, pack_as_tuple<Ts...>> type;
```

it should read:

```
typedef typename replace_nth_type<N,T, pack_as_tuple<Ts...>>::type type;
```

because otherwise your `type` will be of type `replace_nth_type<...>` and not the type that it is supposed to create and which is "returned" as a `typedef` that is also called `type` *within* `replace_nth_type`. Hence you want the `typename replace_nth_type<...>::type` to get the `std::tuple<...>` it created.

Comment: I guess there is still a problem. [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Qqz2V$5) the last assertion should fire, but it doesn't... Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, this solved it, but why did it compile without that additional typename and ::type?

Comment: @DanielFrey: Correct, I just got confused. Sorry about that

Comment: @user2081073: Because you got `replace_nth_type<...>` itself as the type, see my edit.