# For type modification traits, should I provide a template-typedef (aka using) convenience wrapper for typename::transform<...>::type?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I was wondering that with the availability of template-typedefs I should provide convenience wrappers for classes that transform types. Consider this (useless) example:

```
template< T >
struct whatever
{
   typedef typename std::conditional< sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*),
                                      int, long >::type type;
};
```

here, `std::conditional` is `transform` from the title, used with `typename transform<...>::type`. Also, `whatever` itself is also a `transform` and used in the same way.

With the availability of template-typedefs (aka `using`), I could change the interface to:

```
template< T >
using whatever = typename std::conditional< sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*),
                                            int, long >::type;
```

Which simplifies the usage. This could be done for all those cases, but due to the required (partial) specialization, you sometimes end up with an implementation class and a wrapper. In case of `std::conditional`, you'd probably end up with moving it to `std::impl::conditional<...>` and provide another wrapper as

```
namespace std
{
  namespace impl
  {
    // "classic" implementation of std::conditional
  }

  template< bool B, typename T, typename F >
  using conditional = typename impl::conditional< B, T, F >::type;
}
```

This leaves the question what interface/API I should provide. I see one strong point for providing the wrapper: It prevents user errors. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15460637/2073257) question & answer.

For keeping the existing interface, I see the following points:

- Consistency. That's what type traits and basically everybody is using
- Separation of the transformer and the result of the transformation. You can pass the transformer as a type, in case of `whatever` above, this wouldn't be possible anymore.
- Less code by preventing the `impl` solution required for specializations.

I'd like to hear arguments for or against providing the "new" interface, not merely opinions like "I like the second approach better". I'm interested in finding out about cases where one or the other approach is required or when it fails to work/scale.

To be honest, the question is mostly my lack of experience with template-typedefs, so if you do have some real-world experience, please shared the good and the bad side of it and whether or not I should consider the `typename transform<...>::type` API as obsolete with C++11 or not.

Comment: I personally am a fan of template typedefs, though I'm unsure what the right style is. :-)

Comment: Some people decided to go with `CamelCase` for their using-aliases. `template<class T> struct some_trait{ using type = ...; };` and `template<class T> SomeTrait = Invoke<some_trait<T>>;` with `template<class T> using Invoke = typename T::type;`.

Comment: @Xeo: I prefer same identifier as the nested type so that I could write this `type<some_traits<T>>`; likewise `iterator<container>`; `const_iterator<container>`; that way the readability is improved without destroying the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I always do the following:

1. Inside some namespace (impl, detail, etc.) have the classes that do the real work.
2. Outside, have template aliases to clean up calling code.

For example, if I were to re-write std::remove_reference, I would do it like the following:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T> struct remove_reference
    {
        using type = T;
    };
    template <typename T> struct remove_reference<T&>
    {
        using type = T;
    };
    template <typename T> struct remove_reference<T&&>
    {
        using type = T;
    };
}

template <typename T>
using remove_reference = typename detail::remove_reference<T>::type;
```

I didn't compile the above code, so don't shoot me if I made a typo.

A benefit is that the calling site is much more clear. One potential drawback is if you are writing higher order generic code and rely on the existence of a ::type inside of some type function, e.g.

```
template <template <typename...> class F, typename... Ts>
using apply = typename F<Ts...>::type;
```

though you can probably get away with changing the using line to

```
using apply = F<Ts...>;
```

without any harm. It all really comes down to what the rest of your code is doing. If your type functions need to have a certain interface (::type or ::value) then you need to conform to them.

Comment: I know I can do that, that's exactly the example I gave in the question for `std::conditional`, but it doesn't answer the question of whether or not I *should* do it.

Comment: Sorry, I added a brief benefit/drawback at the end there.