# Templates handling functions "returning" more than one value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Sometimes you want a function to return multiple values. One very common way to
achieve such a behavior in C++ is to pass your values by non-const reference and
assign to them in your function:

```
void foo(int & a, int & b)
{
    a = 1; b = 2;
}
```

Which you would use:

```
int a, b;
foo(a, b);
// do something with a and b
```

Now I have a functor that accepts such a function and would want to forward the
set arguments into another function returning the result:

```
template <typename F, typename G>
struct calc;

template <
    typename R, typename ... FArgs,
    typename G
>
struct calc<R (FArgs...), G>
{
    using f_type = R (*)(FArgs...);
    using g_type = G *;

    R operator()(f_type f, g_type g) const
    {
        // I would need to declare each type in FArgs
        // dummy:
        Args ... args;
        // now use the multiple value returning function
        g(args...);
        // and pass the arguments on
        return f(args...);
    }
};
```

Does this approach even make sense, or should I rather use a tuple based
approach? Is there something smarter than a tuple based approach here?

Comment: I guess it depends on the use-case. Using `std::tuple` certainly seems easier. You could also use `std::tuple` as a holder and still use its members to keep `f` and `g` as they are. If you need help with that, let me know and I can post something.

Comment: I really do not like the approach returning values via references to function arguments - return a tuple (You might get some RVO or a r-value reference).

Comment: @DanielFrey I've added a very naive change to `std::tuple`, but I would still be very interested in a way to at least let `f` stay intact to be able to use functions defined in the standard namespace. I agree that it does make sense to return a `std::tuple` for my generator though, following the argumentation of Dieter Lücking.

Comment: In the first simpler example, typically you'd just make a struct of a, b and return the struct, than passing refs that are modified inside. Can you extend the idea to your template function - make the return type a template arg and return value from the functor, when calling it.

Comment: Agree with Deiter - changing the value of a ref can surprise the user of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use compile-time indices:

```
template< std::size_t... Ns >
struct indices
{
    typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template< std::size_t N >
struct make_indices
{
    typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 >
{
    typedef indices<> type;
};

template< typename F, typename G >
struct calc;

template<
   typename R, typename ... FArgs,
   typename G
>
struct calc< R (FArgs...), G >
{
   using f_type = R (*)(FArgs...);
   using g_type = G *;

private:
   template< std::size_t... Ns >
   R impl(f_type f, g_type g, indices< Ns... > ) const
   {
      std::tuple< FArgs ... > args;
      g( std::get< Ns >( args )... );

      // alternatively, if g() returns the tuple use:
      // auto args = g();

      return f( std::get< Ns >( args )... );
   }

public:
   R operator()(f_type f, g_type g) const
   {
      return impl( f, g, typename make_indices< sizeof...( FArgs ) >::type() );
   }
};
```

Comment: This is very neat. I didn't even know you could have compile time indices.

Comment: @nijansen They can be very [useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411022/how-do-i-replace-a-tuple-element-at-compile-time/15412010#15412010) and they will be standardized in C++14 (although with a slightly different name). I just wish this work-around wouldn't be necessary and there would be a more direct way to access the index from a parameter pack while unpacking...

Comment: I did however change one thing: I specialized for both `R (FArgs...)` and `std::tuple<ArgTypes...> ()` because then it plays more nicely with `f` that take arguments as const reference or rvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

When accepting the fact that we're changing the signature of both `f` and `g` to work with `std::tuple`, the answer to this problem becomes trivial:

```
template <typename F, typename G> struct calc;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct calc<R (std::tuple<Args...> const &), std::tuple<Args...> ()>
{
    using f_type = R (*)(std::tuple<Args...> const &);
    using g_type = std::tuple<Args...> (*)();

    R operator()(f_type f, g_type g) const
    {
        return f(g());
    }
};
```

Here is a simple example:

```
int sum(std::tuple<int, int> const & t) { return std::get<0>(t) + std::get<1>(t); }
std::tuple<int, int> gen() { return std::make_tuple<int, int>(1, 2); }

auto x = calc<decltype(sum), decltype(gen)>()(&sum, &gen);
```

The limitation of this solution is clear however: you have to write your own functions. Using something like `std::pow` as `f` is not possible using this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it "trivial". C++ is unrecognisable these days.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Conceptually trivial, not syntactically trivial. Also, you're getting old :/