# Replace N-th element of a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the shortest / best way to replace the n-th element of a tuple with a value (which may or may not have a different type)? Solutions including c++20 are fine. 
[EDIT: I would prefer something not requiring other libraries, but I'm still interested what solutions are possible with e.g. boost].

I.e.:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t N, ... >
auto replace_tuple_element( ... ) // <- Looking for a suitable implementation

struct Foo {
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    auto t1  = std::tuple{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    auto t2 = replace_tuple_element<2>( t1, Foo{10} );

    assert( std::get<0>(t2) == std::get<0>(t1));
    assert( std::get<1>(t2) == std::get<1>(t1));
    assert( std::get<2>(t2).value == 10);
    assert( std::get<3>(t2) == std::get<3>(t1));
}
```

Note: Just replacing the n-th type in a typelist has e.g. be discussed here: [How do I replace a tuple element at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411022/how-do-i-replace-a-tuple-element-at-compile-time/15412010). 
But I also want to replace the value and hope that there are simpler/more elegant solutions now in c++20 than back when that question was asked.

Comment: What is wrong with `std::get<N>` ? Making stuff compiletime is a problem in C++11/14/17 in general.

Comment: @ALX23z: Not sure I understand your question. Nothing is wrong with `std::get<N>` it just doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `std::get<2>(t1) = Foo(10);` how doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: That can't change the type, can it?

Comment: Well, sorry, you were very were unclear about the type replacement (everything in title or emphasized was about the element only) - C++20 still doesn't even have `for` for tuples. For any decent compile time programming features you'll have to wait for `Reflection TS`.

Answer (score 5):

One solution I found for c++20 is this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t N, class TupleT, class NewT>
constexpr auto replace_tuple_element( const TupleT& t, const NewT& n )
{
    constexpr auto tail_size = std::tuple_size<TupleT>::value - N - 1;

    return [&]<std::size_t... I_head, std::size_t... I_tail>
        ( std::index_sequence<I_head...>, std::index_sequence<I_tail...> )
        {
            return std::tuple{
                std::get<I_head>( t )...,
                n,
                std::get<I_tail + N + 1>( t )...
            };
        }(  
           std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, 
           std::make_index_sequence<tail_size>{} 
          );
}

struct Foo {
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    auto t1  = std::tuple{ 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    auto t2 = replace_tuple_element<2>( t1, Foo{10} );

    assert( std::get<0>(t2) == std::get<0>(t1));
    assert( std::get<1>(t2) == std::get<1>(t1));
    assert( std::get<2>(t2).value == 10);
    assert( std::get<3>(t2) == std::get<3>(t1));
}
```

What I like about the solution is that it is a single, self containied function. I wonder if there is something even shorter and/or more readable though.

Comment: Note this decays all element types, removing references and `const`. But I think that might be fixed by adding explicit template arguments on the `return std::tuple{` line. It also misses chances to move if either argument is an rvalue, or fails if a type cannot be copied.

Comment: @aschepler: True, I didn't think about the more generic usecases

Comment: It also doesn't use the same return type if TupleT isn't a std::tuple(...)

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution:

```
template<std::size_t i>
using index = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, i>;

template<std::size_t N, class Tuple, typename S>
auto replace_tuple_element(Tuple&& tuple, S&& s) {
    auto get_element = [&tuple, &s]<std::size_t i>(Index<i>) {
        if constexpr (i == N)
            return std::forward<S>(s);
        else
            return std::get<i>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    };

    using T = std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>;
    return [&get_element]<std::size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(get_element(index<is>{})...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<T>>{});
}
```

---

> Note this decays all element types, removing references and const.

This amendment partially addresses this issue:

```
template<std::size_t N, class Tuple, typename S>
auto replace_tuple_element(Tuple&& tuple, S&& s) {
    using T = std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>;

    auto get_element = [&tuple, &s]<std::size_t i>(index<i>) {
        if constexpr (i == N)
            return std::forward<S>(s);
        else
            if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<std::tuple_element_t<i, T>>)
                return std::ref(std::get<i>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)));
            else
                return std::get<i>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    };

    return [&get_element]<std::size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(get_element(index<is>{})...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<T>>{});
}
```

Now `replace_tuple_element` also follows the convention of [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) that converts `std::reference_wrapper` arguments into references. It does preserve reference types, but drops top-level constness.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int i) : value(i) {}
    int value;
};

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    auto t1 = std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<Foo>(0), std::ref(i), std::cref(j), 4);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t1), 
        std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, int&, const int&, int>>);

    auto t2 = replace_tuple_element<1>(std::move(t1), std::make_unique<Foo>(5));
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t2), 
        std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, std::unique_ptr<Foo>, const int&, int>>);

    auto t3 = replace_tuple_element<0>(std::move(t2), std::cref(i));
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t3), 
        std::tuple<const int&, std::unique_ptr<Foo>, const int&, int>>);

    auto t4 = replace_tuple_element<2>(std::move(t3), i);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t4), 
        std::tuple<const int&, std::unique_ptr<Foo>, int, int>>);
}
```

[Full demo with run-time asserts](https://godbolt.org/z/JqzDsk)

Comment: That looks nice. Currently doesn't compile on msvc on godbolt, but I guess that is a bug in msvc and not in the code (gcc is fine with it).

Comment: Note this decays all element types, removing references and `const`.

Comment: @MikeMB, compiles now with MSVC and `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: Curious, any reason for how you indent your if-else-chain?

Comment: @Deduplicator, the reason is that two conditions are unrelated to each other, so the second `if-else` block is logically in a separate scope. Curly parentheses are redundant, so I did't use them, but preserved indentation. If the second condition had been, say, `i == N + 1`, all `return`s would have begun at the same column.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://godbolt.org/z/K3o4i-) should do it:

```
template<std::size_t N, class U, class T>
auto replace_tuple_element(T&& t, U&& u) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::tuple<std::conditional_t<I == N, U, std::tuple_element_t<I, std::decay_t<T>>>...>{
            [&]() -> decltype(auto) {
                if constexpr (I == N) return std::forward<U>(u);
                else return static_cast<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::decay_t<T>>>(std::get<I>(t));
            }()...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T>>>{});
}
```

You can remove some of the casts, forwards etc. if you're only concerned with value semantics.

The only thing new here is lambda template parameters to infer the indexing argument.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to both preserve all the types exactly as they are, and also do the same kind of reference unwrapping thing that the standard library typically does, then we need to make a small change to what the other implementations are here.

`unwrap_ref_decay` will do a `decay_t` on the type, and then turn `reference_wrapper<T>` into `T&`. And using Boost.Mp11 for a few things that just make everything nicer:

```
template <size_t N, typename OldTuple, typename NewType>
constexpr auto replace_tuple_element(OldTuple&& tuple, NewType&& elem)
{
    using Old = std::remove_cvref_t<OldTuple>;
    using R = mp_replace_at_c<Old, N, std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<NewType>>;
    static constexpr auto Size = mp_size<Old>::value;

    auto get_nth = [&](auto I) -> decltype(auto) {
        if constexpr (I == N) return std::forward<NewType>(elem);
        else                  return std::get<I>(std::forward<OldTuple>(tuple));
    };

    return [&]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return R(get_nth(mp_size_t<Is>())...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<Size>()); 
}
```

This implementation means that given:

```
std::tuple<int const, int const> x(1, 2);
int i = 42;
auto y = replace_tuple_element<1>(x, std::ref(i));
```

`y` is a `tuple<int const, int&>`.

Comment: It would probably better to have the second template-argument as the type of the new element as inserted, in case the user wants to override it (probably default to `void` as that cannot be inserted). Anyway, nice one.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for a counterpart of `tuple_cat` that, instead of concatenating tuples, gives you a slices of a tuple. Unfortunately, this doesn't exist in the standard library, so we'll have to write it ourselves:

```
template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto tuple_slice(Tuple&& t)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t... Ids> (std::index_sequence<Ids...>)
    {
        return std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Ids, std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>...>
            {std::get<Begin + Ids>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...};
    } (std::make_index_sequence<End - Begin>{});
}
```

Just like `tuple_cat`, this preserve the exact same types of the original tuple.

With `tuple_cat` and `tuple_slice`, the implementation of `replace_tuple_element` feels quite elegant:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename T>
constexpr auto replace_tuple_element(Tuple&& tuple, T&& t)
{
    constexpr auto Size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>;
    return std::tuple_cat(
        tuple_slice<0, N>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)),
        std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(t)),
        tuple_slice<N + 1, Size>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))
    );
}
```

Using `make_tuple` preserves the behavior of turning `reference_wrapper<T>` into `T&`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fhzaRj)